# Question about uncannily similar questions

Tags: discussion

I was reading through some questions and was startled by the similarity between these two, asked by (seemingly) different users about two years apart:

[How to handle co-worker's leg shaking?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30847/how-to-handle-co-workers-leg-shaking)

[How to handle co-worker's loud voices?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91543/how-to-handle-co-workers-loud-voices)

Is this a known template for this type of "co-worker handling" question, or would the latter be classified as plagiarism?

Comment: "How to handle co-worker's... " is a pretty common question here. Lots of people seem to have lots of problems with their coworkers and can't figure out how to handle the situation. And of course reading such a question tends to cause some folks to think "Hey, I have a problem with my coworker. I can ask for help here."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suspicion is that when searching for duplicates prior to posting, the poster encountered that question.  Given that their question is clearly a duplicate many times over, I would suggest that their choice of search criteria was something like "How to handle xxx", which would have thrown up the leg shaking question, rather than anything about noisy co-workers.

They would have then seen that it was an upvoted question, the basic format probably appeared easy enough to adapt, so the poster simply copied and modified the text from that question to suit their needs.

Would it be classified as plagiarism?  Perhaps, but I don't think that was the intent in any way.  The question is clearly a duplicate anyway.